# IE10 console does not return line number on javascript error?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

I am getting this error in the console ( which I do not get in Safari or Firefox )

```
"Unable to get property 'split' of undefined or null reference"
```

But there is no line number. ( Previously, when I received different errors in Firefox and Safari a line number is reported )

Does IE not know where the code it is running is, or does it just not want to tell me.

Comment: Hit F12 and check in console

Comment: Sorry, I am in fact looking in the console.  Updated the question to make that explicit.

Comment: Look to the far right of that statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get IE to fire a breakpoint in its debugger when the exception happens: F12 / Script / Tools dropdown / Break on unhandled exceptions, then Start Debugging.

Comment: It's really a shame that IE doesn't simply display the line numbers on the console like real browsers would... That omission really wastes developer time.